# Probability that a Particle which moves Unit distance in a Random direction on each step will be inside the Unit Sphere after $n$ steps

Tags: calculus, probability, recurrence-relations, integral-equations, geometric-probability

The following integral equation arises while calculating the probability that, a particle which starts at the origin and moves a unit distance in a random direction on each ‘move’, will be within the unit sphere after $n$ moves:
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 
\int_{1-x}^{1+x} \frac{df_{n-1}(t)}{dt}  \left( \frac{x^2-(t-1)^2}{4t} \right) dt, & 0\le x\lt 1  
 \\ f_{n-1} (x-1) + \int_{x-1}^{x+1} \frac{df_{n-1}(t)}{dt}  \left( \frac{x^2 -(t-1)^2}{4t} \right) dt, & 1 \le x \le n-2 
\\ f_{n-1} (x-1) + \int_{x-1}^{n-1} \frac{df_{n-1}(t)}{dt}  \left( \frac{x^2 -(t-1)^2}{4t} \right) dt, & n-2\lt x\lt n 
\\ 1, & x\ge n
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $n \ge 3$. At first glance, this looks quite unsolvable, as it is a mixture of a recurrence relation and an integral equation, that too with differing arguments in $x$. But just to make sure, is there a way to solve for $f_n(x)$? I’m ultimately looking for $f_n(1)$ so it’s also fine if that can be obtained without actually solving the equation.

*Note:* $f_n(x)$ is defined to be the probability that the particle is inside the sphere of radius $x$ centered at the origin after $n$ moves. As the ‘base case’, $$f_2(x) =\begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{4}, & 0\le x\le 2 \\ 1, & x\gt 2 \end{cases}$$

Here are the graphs of $\color{blue}{f_2(x)}, \color{green}{f_3(x)}, \color{red}{f_4(x)} $,

[image]

and some initial values:

$$f_0(1) = 1 \\ f_1(1) = 0 \\ f_2(1) = \frac 14 \\ f_3(1)= \frac 16 \\ f_4(1) = \frac{23}{192} \\ f_5(1) =\frac{11}{120} $$

Comment: iF $x\ge 0$ how do you make sense of $f_n(0.5)$?

Comment: @Paul Actually, $x\ge 1$. Edited.

Comment: Still creates an issue with $f_{n-1} (x-1)$ - just wondering what the domain of the $f_n$ is. Does it have to be n dependent or maybe all of the real line?

Comment: @Paul The domain is $[0,\infty)$ so I think it should be fine.

Comment: But then $f_n (0.5) = f_{n-1} (-0.5) + ...$, so what does $f_{n-1} (-0.5) $ mean?

Comment: @Paul For *that* equation, you can only input values larger than $1$. All this means is that the argument of $f_n$ must be $\ge 0$.

Comment: You need at least one "base case" to properly define this problem, namely $f_0(x)$ or $f_1(x)$. I'm guessing that $f_0(x)$ is $0$ for negative $x$ and $1$ for positive $x$, but I'm not sure. Can you confirm this (and, in case it's necessary, specify what $f_0(0)$ and/or $f_1(0)$ should be)?

Comment: And, just to check, is that $\left(\frac{d}{dt}f_{n-1}(t)\right) \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{1+t^2-x^2}{2t} \right)$ or $\frac{d}{dt} \left(f_{n-1}(t)\cos^{-1} \left( \frac{1+t^2-x^2}{2t} \right)\right)$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla: I myself made little progress on this but I'll share a few things that I believe are correct and helpful. First, $f_n$ is a cumulative distribution function. I'd made the mistake initially of thinking of these things as densities. Secondly, it might be analytically easier to think in terms of each $f_n$ being defined on all of $(-\infty, \infty)$ because of that. In this case $f_0$ is simply the step function. Thirdly, at least from the background info on these representing jumps, at time step $n$ the particle can't get beyond $x = n$, so you have $f_n(x) = 1$ for $x > n$. Best!

Comment: @Aruralreader If the step function is the floor function, there's no way that $f_0$ could be that. It has to be between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The step function, the Heaviside step function, the unit step function: $f(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$, $1$ otherwise. Good luck!

Comment: @VarunVejalla The domain is only the non-negative reals. $f_0(x) = 0$ for $x=0$ and $1$ for $x\gt 0$. I can also provide $f_1$, which is $0$ for $0\le x\le 1$ and $1$ for $x\gt 1$. Also, the $\cos^{-1}$ is outside of the derivative.

Comment: @Aruralreader ‘s comment is correct.

Comment: You say $x\ge 1$ for $f_n (x) = f_{n - 1} (x - 1) +  \cdots$. So that gives $f_n$ for $x\ge 1$. But then in the next step $f_{n + 1} (x) = f_n (x - 1) +  \cdots$ and the right-hand side makes sense only if $x-1\geq 1$, i.e., $x\geq 2$. And so on. At each step, the domain shrinks. So the condition on $x$ should be $x\ge n$.

Comment: @Gary That’s a good point. But because the area of interest *is* $0\le x\le n$, I guess I will have to divide into cases. Any problems now?

Comment: On second thought, it might be better to start from $f_2$, since neither $f_0$ nor $f_1$ are continuous (and the derivative is equal to $0$ everywhere except at $x=1$ for $f_1$)

Comment: To prevent clutter in the comments, I created a chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120775/room-for-particle-ending-inside-sphere

Answer (score 2):

**NOT AN ANSWER**.

I know that Borwein studied that problem in various papers. The following one seems to be relevant to you:

Jonathan M. Borwein, Armin Straub, Christophe Vignat. Densities of short uniform random walks in higher dimensions. Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications, Elsevier, 2016, 437 (1), pp.668-707. 10.1016/j.jmaa.2016.01.01

I hope this link works; https://hal-centralesupelec.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01261938/document

Comment: From that paper (and after using some other relations), you can get that $f_n(1) = \frac{1}{2^{n}\left(n+1\right)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2 \rfloor}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{n+1}{k}\left(n+1-2k\right)^{n}$

Comment: Thank you @GiuseppeNegro.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Did you use Corollary $2.2$ (Page $5$) to get that?

Comment: @Tavish: You're welcome, I really didn't do much. I just searched the web for "Borwein random walk", that paper was one of the first hits. Varun Vejalla worked much harder than I did.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro No doubt, shout out to Varun.

Comment: I probably should have read further, as I just used $p_n(v;x)$, not the formula that they already obtained, but you can also use corollary $2.2$. With $d = 3$, the Bessel functions are especially convenient because they have closed forms in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I tried to derive that expression on my own, but got stuck on evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \left( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right)^{n+1} dx $, did a google search and I got it. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

For one-dimensional case see Theorem 5 on page 2: [https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~nayar/wdk_2020/notatki_wdk_2020.pdf](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/%7Enayar/wdk_2020/notatki_wdk_2020.pdf)
Maybe You will find a way to generalise it to more dimensions.

I suck at probability so I cannot help more.